# How to use SqLite in JAVAFX Application in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sqlite, javafx, installation, inno-setup

I have created an application in eclipse using JAVAFX. I have included SQLite in build path as shown in image. Then, I created the Executable JAR file as shown second image. Then, created EXE using INNO Setup. The Created JAR was included in the Inno. After installing on other system, it seems that SQLite is not working or installed with this application.

1. Do I need to install SQLite separately ? or
2. Is it required to include the SQLite folder in Inno also ? or
3. Need to launch SQLite installer programmatically in the application during installation ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyBl8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS3Al.png)

Comment: You should just follow the recommended practice to create an application bundle/installer. Have a look at the **Packaging** section here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info If you follow these guidelines including SQLite works like a charm. I do that regularly.

Comment: Now, after an year, I answer myself above 3 queries in my question. 
1. There is no need to install SQLite separately on target PC or Laptop, rather integrate SQLite library -jar in the project. It will be bundled automatically in the application -jar.
2. No
3. No

Answer (score -2):

Add sqlite-db jar and sql jar to build path of project.